# Google Apps Script - clasp - failed to create script

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, clasp

Following [THIS](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/clasp/#3) tutorial on codelabs.developers.google.com:

When I run this command `clasp create "clasp Codelab"` to create a standalone script I get the message:

> Please login. (clasp login)

Though I have already run the command `login` before that which opens the browser with the pop showing:

> clasp – The Apps Script CLI wants to access your Google Account
>
> ALLOW

On selecting ALLOW, I get

> Logged in! You may close this page.

I can not figure out what I am missing here. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT 1: I am using Windows 10 (64 BIT). Node.js version 8.11.1

Comment: On macOS, completing the authentication flow should create the file `~/.clasprc.json`. Was that created, and do you access token, token type, and refresh token inside the file?

Comment: I am sorry I should have mentioned, I am using windows 10.

Comment: Hm... Please try to login `> clasp login --no-localhost` Perhaps your firewall is blocking the clasp local server or its port.

Comment: Perfect! Can you post this as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer here is to login first:

```
clasp login --no-localhost
```

As mentioned in the comment.

---

On a different note, I updated the codelab to state:

```
clasp create --title "clasp Codelab"
```

Since the `--title` change was a breaking change in the early days of `clasp`.